# How to save nvd3 graph in a pdf?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using nvd3 to generate Data-visualization for my project, now i need to save the image in a pdf on click of a button. can anyone help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to create PDF files, you can use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) PHP library.